# Does Spring Cloud Config support reading yaml sequences?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

In my Spring Cloud Config yaml file can I use a sequence? I would like to map a yaml sequence to a Java ArrayList and have the values injected.

An example would be something like this.

YAML File:

```
american:
  - Boston Red Sox
  - Detroit Tigers
  - New York Yankees
```

Java Spring Bean:

```
@Value("${american}")
List<String> american;
```

Answer (score 5):

It is just a feature of Spring Boot: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

It shows an example of yaml lists.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that in the doc. I somehow missed it the first time through.

Comment: @spencergibb while it does have an example it fails to provide a usage example. How do I `getServers()`?